# What really happened on the boat in Blackwater?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

At the start of the game the entire gang is fleeing due to the events that happened in Blackwater. From what some of the other gang members tell you, there was a heist planned on a boat, and it went horribly wrong somehow. And now law enforcement and the Pinkertons are chasing after the gang.

There are some allusions to what happened in the first chapter conversations, but there doesn't seem to be a clear explanation of the details. Are the details of the events intentionally left unclear for the entire game, or are there some actual accounts of what happened on the boat in Blackwater?

Another suspicion based on the events much later in the game (be warned, this contains a serious spoiler for the last chapters):

> We get to know that Micah was an informant later in the game. My original understanding was that he only started to pass information at a later point, but are there any hints or evidence that he might already had a hand in ensuring that the Blackwater events lead to disaster?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question

> are there any hints or evidence that he might already have had a hand in ensuring that the Blackwater events lead to disaster?

No

> It is stated that Micah turned spy after the gang returned from the Island.

As far as an explanation for your main question

> Are the details of the events intentionally left unclear for the entire game, or are there some actual accounts of what happened on the boat in Blackwater?

, We do not know any details about what went wrong in Blackwater. We know that it was a failed Ferry heist that resulted in several deaths of fellow gang members and the gang is trying to make enough money to retire for good. If you're wondering where my information is coming from, I've completed the game twice and have quite a good memory :)